# What value does UIScreen.main.bounds return? Trouble with matching size of screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Documentations and other guides have suggested to me that UIScreen.main.bounds in Swift returns the edges of the screen. However, using the simulator in Swift this does not turn out to be the case.

Below are two screenshots from the XCode Simulator (5s, 6) using the same code.

[iPhone5s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo8Uh.png)
[iPhone6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhFV1.png)

The code is below, but essentially just draw four paths around with coordinates of (screenwidth,screenheight),(-screenwidth,screenheight),(screenwidth,-screenheight),(-screenwidth,-screenheight).

Am I misunderstanding UIScreen.main.bounds? Or is there something else causing this? Ideally, I want to be able to programmatically set variables that find the four corners of the screen.

This is all done in GameScene. I added no features on the storyboard.

```
    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width
    let screenHeight = screenSize.height
    let pathBound = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: -screenWidth, y: -screenHeight, width: 5, height: screenHeight*2))
    let shapeNode = SKShapeNode(path: pathBound.cgPath)
    shapeNode.fillColor = UIColor.green
    shapeNode.strokeColor = UIColor.green
    addChild(shapeNode)
    let pathBound2 = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: screenWidth-5, y: -screenHeight, width: 5, height: screenHeight*2))
    let shapeNode2 = SKShapeNode(path: pathBound2.cgPath)
    shapeNode2.fillColor = UIColor.blue
    shapeNode2.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
    addChild(shapeNode2)
    let pathBound3 = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: -screenWidth, y: screenHeight-5, width: screenWidth*2, height: 5))
    let shapeNode3 = SKShapeNode(path: pathBound3.cgPath)
    shapeNode3.fillColor = UIColor.red
    shapeNode3.strokeColor = UIColor.red
    addChild(shapeNode3)
    let pathBound4 = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: -screenWidth, y: -screenHeight, width: screenWidth*2, height: 5))
    let shapeNode4 = SKShapeNode(path: pathBound4.cgPath)
    shapeNode4.fillColor = UIColor.orange
    shapeNode4.strokeColor = UIColor.orange
    addChild(shapeNode4)
    let pathBound5 = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: -screenWidth, y: 0
        , width: screenWidth*2, height: 5))
    let shapeNode5 = SKShapeNode(path: pathBound5.cgPath)
    shapeNode5.fillColor = UIColor.purple
    shapeNode5.strokeColor = UIColor.purple
    addChild(shapeNode5)
```

Comment: UIScreen.main.bounds returns the CGRect(origin: CGPoint, size: CGSize) for all devices , suppose you are using like this :  UIScreen.main.bounds.size then it returns the various bounds size like : (320 , 480) , (320 , 568) , (375 , 667) , (414 , 736)

Answer (score 0):

**What you think about this-**

```
var screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width


var screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
```